# How to find sum of n number using clojure for loop macro?

Tags: macros, clojure

I'm using a for-loop macro in clojure:

```
 (defmacro for-loop [[sym initial check-exp post-exp] & steps]
 `(loop [~sym ~initial]
    (if ~check-exp
      (do
        ~@steps
        (recur ~post-exp)))))
```

I want to write a simple function to find the sum of n numbers like:

```
for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
sum=sum+i;
```

How can I do this in clojure using the for-loop macro?

Comment: Having a variable and updating its value is not idiomatic clojure, you probably want something like `(reduce + (range (inc n)))`.

Comment: But, this happens without using the for-loop macro only. Is there anyway to use the for loop macro? I'm trying to learn macros, hence asking.

Comment: By "learn macros", do you mean "learn writing macros"? Or "learn using macros"? Because the latter does not require that much specialised knowledge (some documentation, though) and it is definitely a prerequisite to the former one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(def sum (atom 0))
(def n 100)

(for-loop [i 0 (< i n) (inc i)] (swap! sum #(+ % i)))
```

Comment: Hi @Lee, it gives a nil value.

Comment: @MarthaPears - Yes the loop evaluates to nil but `@sum` contains the sum. The loop is only executed for its effects.

Comment: Using an external atom is really not idiomatic.

Comment: @schaueho - Unless I'm missing something the `for-loop` macro always evaluates to `nil` so you have to use external state if you want to use it to calculate a value.

Comment: Yes, I agree that this is probably the only way if one sticks with using the exact `for-loop` macro as provided.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no need to use a macro here. Second, your use of `do` with the final call to `recur` will prevent the macro from ever returning a value other than nil as discussed in Lee's answer. That you should use `when` instead of `if` when you're not really providing an `else` case is only a slight matter, but hints at a possible better solution: Use the else case to return the result. For this to work you need to introduce an accumulator into the equation.

```
(defmacro for-loop [[sym initial result initial-result check-exp post-exp] & steps]
 `(loop [~sym ~initial
         ~result ~initial-result]
    (if ~check-exp
      (do
        ~@steps
        (recur ~@post-exp))
      ~result)))
```

This is still pretty ugly, but allows you to solve your summing task like this, actually not requiring any intermediate steps:

```
 (for-loop [i 0 r 0 (< i n) ((inc i) (+ r i))] nil)
```

If you macro-expand this, it's easier to see that is going on:

```
 (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(for-loop [i 0 r 0 (< i n) ((inc i) (+ r i))] nil)))
 ==> (clojure.core/loop [i 0 r 0]
       (if (< i n) 
           (do nil 
               (recur (inc i) (+ r i))) 
           r))
```

It would be nice if one would not have to explicitly name and use the accumulator but just use the results from the `steps`, but as the steps will likely need to refer to any intermediate values build up so far as in this example, there is no way around it.